# Spring boot formLogin using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, spring-security

I have a very similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60958724/authenticate-user-in-spring-boot-with-react-login-form).
My Spring boot backend has formLogin configured using this Bean :

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin();
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    return http.build();
}
```

My React app is running port 3000, while the backend is running on port 8080, how can redirect unauthenticated requests to `localhost:3000/myLoginPage` ?

After reading some SO questions, i wana point out that changing the port for the React app by modifying the package.json like so :

```
"scripts": {
     "dev": "next dev -p 8080",
```

is not a viable solution in my case, the app wont run since the backend is running on port 8080.

My goal is to redirect the user to another application ( the React app ) and change the default login page generated by spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specify loginPage in formLogin

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("http://localhost:3000/myLoginPage"));
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    return http.build();
}
```